# Java : Adding objects to a list of objects

Tags: java, struts2

Its very simple but somehow not working (weird!!).

I have a List of a class type. I am adding objects to the list in a for loop. Up till adding object everything is Ok, but as soon as I try to access the list, only the last object's values are shown (refer to the output I have shown below). Also here is the code:

```
    List<myClass> myClassList = new ArrayList<myClass>();
    myClass myClassObj = new myClass();

    for(int i=0;i<someArray.length;i++){
        myClassObj.setProperty1("value1");
        myClassObj.setProperty2("value2");
        myClassObj.setProperty3("value3");
        ...
        ...Others
        ...
        System.out.println(myClassList.add(myClassObj));////////////////////////
    }

    System.out.println(myClassList.size());/////////////////////////////////////

    for(int i=0;i<myClassList.size();i++){
        System.out.println(myClassList.get(i).getProperty1());/////////////////
        .....
        .....Others
        .....
    }
    Iterator<myClass> mcItr = myClassList.iterator();
    while(mcItr.hasNext()){
        myClass obj = mcItr.next();
        System.out.println(obj.getProperty1());
        .....
        .....Others
        .....
    }
```

The **output** of this program is (if the size of `someArray` is **5**) :

```
    //'true' --> 5 times. Printed by the 'add' statement as it returns 'true' when everything is OK

    //5  --> Size of 'myClassList' this is also OK

    //Here the values corresponding to the fifth and the last object are printed and repeated 5 times. Instead of printing each objects value once. (whichever way of printing to console I may use, the result is same).
```

Here I can not figure out whether I am creating the list in a wrong way or accessing it in a wrong way.

Please advice.

Thanks!!

Comment: same class refrence is the culprit

Comment: You need to put 'myClass myClassObj = new myClass();' inside the first FOR loop. Else you are simply overwriting the initial variable with new values.

Comment: BTW Java naming conventions says, that Classes should start with a upper case letter. e.g. MyClass instead of myClass

Comment: @Andreas : Yeah you right. I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When populating the list, you are repeatedly adding references **to the same object**. To fix, move the `myClassObj` initialization into the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<someArray.length;i++){
    myClass myClassObj = new myClass(); // <---- moved this into the loop
    myClassObj.setProperty1("value1");
```

This will create a separate object for every element of the list.

Comment: Oh yes!! You are right!! I knew it was gonna be something like that. Thanks!!

Comment: @kanishk Don't forget to accept the answers that have helped you.

Comment: @NickBull : Answer cannot be accepted until 10-15 minutes. Was about to do that. Thanks for the reminder anyways :) !!

Answer (score 2):

You need create a new myClassObj every time, your code uses the same object reference.

```
List<myClass> myClassList = new ArrayList<myClass>();

    for(int i=0;i<someArray.length;i++){
        myClass myClassObj = new myClass(); // HERE
        myClassObj.setProperty1("value1");       
        ...
        System.out.println(myClassList.add(myClassObj));////////////////////////
    }
```